# variable not displaying it's output php

Tags: php, html, web, e-commerce

Given this php block:

```
<?php
//This block grabs whole list for viewing
$product_list = "";
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=mysql9.000webhost.com;dbname=a9802737_mystore', 'a9802737_mystore', 'mystore1');
$sql= $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC");
$sql->execute();
$productCount = $sql->fetchColumn(); //count the output amount
if($productCount>0){

             while($row = $sql->fetch()){ 
                 $id = $row["id"];
                 $product_name = $row["product_name"];
                 $price = $row["productPrice"];
                 $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
                 $product_list .= "Product ID: $id - <strong>$product_name</strong> - $$price - <em>Added $date_added</em> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href='inventory_edit.php?pid=$id'>edit</a> &bull; <a href='inventory_list.php?deleteid=$id'>delete</a><br/>";


             }



} else{
    $product_list = "You have no products listed in your store yet.";
}

?>
```

As you can see I declared $product_list and initialized it with a blank string first then in the while loop I updated it's value. I called $product_list again in a php block

```html
<div align = "right" style="margin-right:32px;"><a href="#inventory_list.php#inventoryForm">+ Add New T-Shirt</a></div>
<div align="left"style="margin-left:24px">
  <h2>Inventory List</h2>
    <?php echo $product_list; ?>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

And the value it show's is the ""(blank) string not the updated one.

[image]

When it should look like this:

[image]

Comment: $$price in $product_list concatenation

Comment: You have used  concatenation operator (`.=`) to assign value to the variable `$product_list`. Did you declare `$product_list` earlier?

Comment: @SazzadurRahman yes I declared it $product_list = " ";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
//This block grabs whole list for viewing
$product_list = "";
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=mysql9.000webhost.com;dbname=a9802737_mystore', 'a9802737_mystore', 'mystore1');

$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC");
$sql->execute();

if($sql->rowCount()) {

    while($row = $sql->fetch()) { 
        $id = $row["id"];
        $product_name = $row["product_name"];
        $price = $row["productPrice"];
        $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
        $product_list .= "Product ID: $id - <strong>$product_name</strong> - $$price - <em>Added $date_added</em> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href='inventory_edit.php?pid=$id'>edit</a> &bull; <a href='inventory_list.php?deleteid=$id'>delete</a><br/>";
    }
} else {
    $product_list = "You have no products listed in your store yet.";
}

?>
```

here

```
if ($sql->rowCount()) {
    //
}
```

condition will check weather the query returns any results or not.

Comment: You should be careful. As it is written in [PDO documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) :

`If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are running query, which selects only count of items:

```
$sql= $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC");
```

So, `fetchColumn()` method return number of products, but `fetch()` does not return items.
For fetching results you should make like this:

```
$sql= $db->query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC");
while($row = $sql->fetch()){ 
                 $id = $row["id"];
                 $product_name = $row["product_name"];
                 $price = $row["productPrice"];
                 $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
                 $product_list .= "Product ID: $id - <strong>$product_name</strong> - $$price - <em>Added $date_added</em> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href='inventory_edit.php?pid=$id'>edit</a> &bull; <a href='inventory_list.php?deleteid=$id'>delete</a><br/>";


             }
```

Comment: I need SELECT COUNT(*) to get the productCount. Then if productCount>0 then I will fetch results.

Comment: In case of empty results `while` loop just won't run. So you still will have $product_list as empty string ( initiated in very begining of script).
 
@Andre or you also need to know count of products? than you can just use $productCount++ in every iteration of while